# Flutter : snapshot.data no longer works

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wrote an android app in Flutter about 2 years ago, but it was never used. I have now been asked If I can resurrect it, I'm aware there has been quite a few changes over the last 2 years, but I didn't want to re-write it. It has a simple Firebase chat as well as using the Firebase Auth, most of with is now working again. I am really struggling with this section.

I am getting an error on the `snapshot.data`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, Thanks

```
 FutureBuilder(
      future: getShared(widget.checkKey),
      initialData: false,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Checkbox(
          value: snapshot.data,
             onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              putShared(widget.checkKey, value!);
            });
          },
          //activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        );
      })
```

**Error**

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the class type for `getShared` method.

```
Future<bool>getShared(...){
   ...
}
```

Also `FutureBuilder`

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getShared(widget.checkKey),
          ...
    )
```